# why java is not supporting tripple equals

Tags: java

This is my code.but my question why java is not supporting this operator where is other langauge is supporting like php,javascript.

```
int a=1;
float b=1;

if(a===b)
    out.println("true");
else
    out.println("false");
```

Comment: You might want to ask why JavaScript needs `===` instead (most other languages don't).

Comment: [JavaScript supports this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1065197) but Java **is not** JavaScript.

Comment: k..i will ask but why you reduce mark because of you people other person not aksing question.as every body not like u..k.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP and JavaScript allow to check the type of a variable by using this operator. This isn't necessary in Java, because its typing is static.

Answer (score 3):

The === operator performs a deep comparison and checks for type equality also. The equivalent in java is to override equals() and hashCode() to provide a contract that performs a deep equals() check. Java does not need a '==='.